# How do I make tests repeatable in Cypress?

Tags: testing, integration-testing, cypress, end-to-end

I have a site with various user types, (e.g. admin, client, etc.) while they all have functionality that is specific to their user type there is also some functionality that is shared. How do I define a set of tests so that they can be run when logged in as one user type, then run again when logged in as another user type?

I know about Cypress.Commands.add() but I haven't found a way to use it for a large set of repeatable tests, only for repeating the inner content of a single test.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how many common scenarios you have you could use a data-driven approach, something like:

```
context('common scenarios', () => {
    const credentials = [
        {userName: "user1", password: "password1", userType: "admin"},
        {userName: "user2", password: "password2", userType: "client"}
    ]

    credentials.forEach(cr => {
        it(`should be able to login as ${cr.userType}`, () => {
            // ...
            // use cr.userName, etc...
            // ...
        })
    })
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however this won't work for my use case as there are different steps for each user type to get to the shared parts, and I also don't want everything in one massive file.